# Custom style for paragraph with numbering format in a Word Document with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am working on Open XML word document, my requirement on this is to add custom styles into word document style gallery. I did this but problem is with numbering style, I want **Number** (1, 2, 3, ... etc) for **QuestionText** and **UpperLetter** (A, B, C,... etc) for **QuestionChoice** like below

Example:

1. This is question text which had indent 0.5 for question number to question text and wrap text below to number?
   A. Option text1
   B. Option text2

And more clarification on this I attached image document.

Word document sample

[image]

Comment: There is a XML Document Explorer tool ( OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi) available from Microsoft to allow you to inspect a document.  You could use that tool to help reverse-engineer the elements you need to create.   here's a link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: Mr. Glenn Ferrie, Thank you for your suggestion and thanks for formatting my First question in stack overflow.

Comment: Hello Mr. Glenn Ferrie, After I did reverse-engineer I got expected result. but the problem is options A, B, C, D... is not restart/reset for next questions. And one more think is I want to bind html content to the word document. actually I did also by using 'AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html' feature of Open XML, but challenges is unable to apply Format style from style gallery.